# Docker load and save: "archive/tar: invalid tar header"

Tags: linux, docker, redhat, tar, docker-image

I'm trying to import a Docker image into Docker on AWS Red Hat Linux (3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64) and am having problems with the error;

```
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): archive/tar: invalid tar header
```

This same image works fine on my local machine, and in Boot2Docker on Windows also. It's quite large (2.5 GB), but I've verified the checksum on the Red Hat Linux instance, and it's the same as from the source.

What could be wrong, or how I can resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried pushing it to a registry and pulling it down on the Red Hat box? You get to store one image for free on Docker Hub so you can try it out. If that works, provide the minimal steps needed to reproduce the problem, including how (and on what system) you built the image.

Answer (score 99):

I wanted to add that the issue probably occurs because of the difference in behaviour of STDOUT between Windows and Unix. Therefore, using the STDOUT way of saving like:

`docker save [image] > file.tar` followed by `docker load < file.tar`

will not work if the `save` and `load` are executed on a different OS. Always use:

`docker save [image] -o file.tar` followed by `docker load -i file.tar`

to prevent these issues. Comparing the TAR files produced by the different methods, you will find that they have a completely different size (303MB against 614MB for me).

Comment: I've been trying to figure out why my image ballooned in size by 2x all day -- this was it.  You're the best and everybody loves you.

Comment: Spot on! Saved the day my friend.

Comment: Like @ChrisBarlow said, I love you.

Answer (score 30):

As a more detailed description to Ostecke's answer.

I've found it's not a windows specific issue. It's a powershell issue. Powershell emits two byte characters to STDOUT, not one byte characters. If you look in the file you'll notice that the TAR header has nulls between what should be the correct header (and in the rest of the file). This explains why the file is twice the size.

CMD on the other hand does not emit multibyte characters to STDOUT. I've found the STDOUT method of saving a file works fine across different OSes if you use CMD on windows.

Using powershell, only the -o option is safe:

```
docker save [image] -o file.tar
```

Using CMD, either method should work fine.

Comment: Exactly, using CMD instead of PowerShell while placing -o for save and -i for load worked for me :) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Used it and all went smooth.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to resolve this problem is this:

When you save the image, use this instruction

```
Docker save --output=C:\YOUR_PATH\my_docker_image.tar e6f81ac424ae(image id)
```

And when you try to load this image, use this instruction:

```
Docker load --input C:\YOUR_PATH\my_docker_image.tar
```

After this you see your image with name <none> in Docker image, and to resolve this, use the command tag

```
Docker tag IMAGE_ID mydockerapplication
```

Comment: docker load --input C:\YOUR_PATH\my_docker_image.tar
worked wonders for me

Comment: How do you know which is the image if there are other <none> s previously?

Comment: And it didn't work for me (I am in ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in FTPing the TAR file to my AWS instance - the FTP client was defaulting to ASCII mode instead of binary. Once I set it to binary I had no problems importing the archive.

Comment: Can't you use an HTTP transfer instead of FTP?

Answer (score 0):

Use podman push instead of skopeo.

Ex:

```
skopeo -skopeo:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.tgz

podman - podman:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.tgz
```

Comment: please double check the edit and correct if needed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).