# Docker API: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): archive/tar: invalid tar header

Tags: docker, docker-api

I want to upload a zip file to my tomcat container using docker API.

`http://{mydockerHost}:2375/containers/{containerId}/archive?path=/usr/local/tomcat/`

But this i am getting this kind of expection,

```
{
    "message": "Error processing tar file(exit status 1): archive/tar: invalid tar header"
}
```

Kindly solve my problem, Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you uploading the file? Where does the error message come from?

Comment: @MarteValerioFalcone I am using postman to do this

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622162/docker-load-and-save-archive-tar-invalid-tar-header) answer to your question?

Comment: Remember that anyone who can reach the Docker socket can pretty trivially root the host; if you're allowing unencrypted connections to the Docker socket on port 2375, that means anyone on your local network can take over your machine.  I'd disable the relevant Docker daemon option _immediately_, and use only the Unix socket file to talk to Docker (still speaks HTTP but not over TCP).

Comment: @DavidMaze then how can I send my files to a container? 
For my project I need to send some files to the container using docker api. So how can I do it?

Comment: @MarteValerioFalcone the error was same, Here i did this via docker api.

Comment: Typically you'd run something like an HTTP service in your container, publish its port with a `docker run -p` option, and make an HTTP POST request to the service.  Unless you're specifically trying to manage containers, I'd avoid the (high-risk, less-portable) Docker API.

Answer (score 0):

seem you need to download manually the specific docker image file then:

// 1- extract file

// 2- then run this command in its folder

// in my case neo4j docker image

use this:

```
docker load -i .\neo4j
```

instead of this

```
docker load -i .\neo4j.7z
```

// Error processing tar file(exit status 1): archive/tar: invalid tar header